# iOS Push device tokens getting always BadDeviceToken

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

I hope I find a person who can help me. I have a iOS App in the App Store and the push device tokens I get, are wrong. Over the APNS Server (production and sandbox) I always get the answer: BadDeviceToken.

The app is developed with cordova, ionic and I use the phonegap push plugin.

When I deploy the app in debug mode directly to my iPhone, I get a token that is valid in sandbox and production.

But all tokens I actually get from iOS are all wrong.

Comment: I had this the other day and the problem was that I was using the wrong server/certificate combination. I would try double checking that first.

Comment: I use the APNsAuthKey. And I think with this I have access to all my apps.

Comment: @PhillipPlum How did you solve this?

Comment: @Sarit nothing, after a while it works again by itself :/